# Entries not being searched in the control panel

Tags: entries, control-panel, entry, entry-type

I have a 'person' channel that does away with the title field and instead uses custom fields like so `{lastName}, {firstName}`.

However, I've noticed that when I'm looking at the entries listing in the control panel and I search for 'Hamilton' as an example (I have 3 entries where the surname is Hamilton) - only 1 of the entries returns.

I even tried adding myself as an entry to the channel but searching for `Grant` or even `Steven` - I get no returns.

Can't figure out why this would be?

Comment: Updating the search indexes was the solution here although still need to search `hamilton` in its entirety before entries appear, I can't just search `ham` for example. I'm hoping there's a better way to enable this?

Comment: You'll want to enable [Fuzzy Searching](https://craftcms.com/support/enabling-fuzzy-search-by-default) to get partial words to [match](https://craftcms.com/docs/searching). New in 2.5.

Comment: @StevenGrant Would you mind adding that as an official answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updating the search indexes was the solution here. In addition, I also enabled [Fuzzy Searching](https://craftcms.com/support/enabling-fuzzy-search-by-default) for partial matches